# Automate Notion Database with Apple's Shorcut App

Tags: notion-api

I was wondering where I could find information on how to make a shortcut (on **Apple's Shorcuts App**) for editing a database on Notion (without the need to go into Notion).

I saw a video recently where a new entry (shortcut asks for the input) could be added to a database, but I also want to make the shortcut ask for its properties.

Say, for instance, that I have a Read Books database with the properties "name", "author", "price". How can I link both apps to do this? Any sites on this topic?

Thank you!